# ¿Se puede transformar esta fecha por PHP o MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

tengo la siguiente fecha: Sat, 30 May 2020 07:25:30 +0000
¿Se puede transformar usando PHP o MySQL al siguiente formato?

Como esta:
Sat, 30 May 2020 07:25:30 +0000

Como debería estar:
2020-05-30 07:25:30

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En PHP podrías primero leer el string inicial para convertirlo a tipo fecha:

`$fecha = date_create_from_format('D, d M Y h:i:s O', 'Sat, 30 May 2020 07:25:30 +0000');`

y luego:

`$fechaFormateada = date ( 'Y-m-d h:i:s', date_timestamp_get($fecha))`

En el manual de PHP están todos los formatos posibles: https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php